# how to right choose javascript pattern

Tags: javascript, object, design-patterns, architecture, pattern-matching

i create 2 objects:

```
  var Documentos = new QuadForm();
  var Cadastro = new QuadForm();
```

And initialize this objects with lot of options

```
    Cadastro.initForm(options);
    Documentos.initForm(options2);
```

then i try to separate the data managed by each object with **getName** method but after the second object, ***myObjectName*** variable is overrided.

```
    var QuadForm;
QuadForm = function () {
    this.getName = function () {
        // search through the global object for a name that resolves to this object
        for (var name in window)
            if (window[name] == this) {
                window[name] = this;
                window[window[name]] = window[name];
                myObjectName= name;
                break;
            }
    },
        this.initForm = function (parms) {

            this.getName()

            $.extend(this, parms);
            if (window.myState) {
                delete window.myState;
            }
            this.containerId = parms.formId;
            this.getForm(parms);
            this.workflowLabels('hide');
```

then i use window[***myObjectName***].totalRecords but as it changes to the latest object name off course cannot access data.

How can i manage this.

Comment: What is your target? Are you trying to find each instance of your constructor `QuadForm`? Then let me say you have no chance to do that in a way which matches all cases!
Anyway it is clear, that you variable is overwritten, cause you overwrite it several times.

Comment: it not possible to do that? two instances in same view and the class quadform managing data from several instances?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a big problem to manage several instances, but your approach is impossible, cause you can't really find all possible instances and your code does definitely not what you expected to do.

For example you can define a variable on the constructor-object which holds all instances, and than you can use it in some cases:

```
var QuadForm = function (name) {
  this.name = name;

  QuadForm.instances.push(this);

  this.showAllOtherInstances = function () {
    QuadForm.instances.forEach(function (instance) {
      if (instance !== this) {
        console.log('name: ' + instance.name);
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }
}

QuadForm.instances = [];

var foo = new QuadForm('foo');
var anotherFoo = new QuadForm('foo');
var bar = new QuadForm('bar');
var aThirdFoo = new QuadForm('foo');
foo.showAllOtherInstances();
/* 
 * Output:
 *
 * name: foo
 * name: bar
 * name: foo
 */
```